# Ruby LibXML skip large nodes

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing, libxml2

I have an xml file that has a very large text node (>10 MB). While reading the file, is it possible to skip (ignore) this node?

I tried the following:

```
 reader = XML::Reader.io(path)
 while reader.read do
  next if reader.name.eql?('huge-node')
 end
```

But this still results in the error `parser error : xmlSAX2Characters: huge text node`

The only other solution I can think of is to first read the file as a string and remove the huge node through a gsub, and then parse the file. However, this method seems very inefficient.

Comment: Did you absolutely need to use the SAX parser?

Comment: Ah, ok. That certainly makes the problem more challenging. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If you only want get around the "huge text node" error, pass the [`HUGE`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/ParseOptions#HUGE-constant) option.

Comment: @nwellnhof thanks for pointing that out; however, I am not using nokogiri.

Comment: Then try the [`HUGE`](http://xml4r.github.io/libxml-ruby/rdoc/classes/LibXML/XML/Parser/Options.html) option of libxml-ruby.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because by the time you are trying to skip it, it's already read the node. According to the [documentation](http://xml4r.github.io/libxml-ruby/rdoc/classes/LibXML/XML/Reader.html#method-i-read) for the `#read` method:

```
reader.read -> nil|true|false
Causes the reader to move to the next node in the stream, exposing its properties.

Returns true if a node was successfully read or false if there are no more nodes to read. On errors, an exception is raised.
```

You would need to skip the node prior to calling the `#read` method on it. I'm sure there are many ways you could do that but it doesn't look like this library supports XPath expressions, or I would suggest something like that.

**EDIT:** The question was clarified so that the SAX parser is a required part of the solution. I have removed links that would not be helpful given this constraint.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That clarifies why my attempt was unsuccessful. Any other ideas of how to skip the node prior to calling the `#read` method on it?

Comment: Perhaps you could catch the error and then call `reader.next`? I'm not exactly sure if that would work because I don't have this library or a representative XML file to test with.

Comment: There's also some [options](http://xml4r.github.io/libxml-ruby/rdoc/classes/LibXML/XML/Parser/Options.html) you can pass to the parser that may help. Most interesting would be `RECOVER`, I think.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those out!

Comment: @diasks2 did you ever get this sorted out?

Comment: I didn't have any success with your suggestions (most likely just due to my own inability to correctly implement them). Currently I am using `File.read` and using `gsub` to remove the unwanted nodes and then putting that string in the `XML::Reader.string()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to skip the node. The cause is that since version 2.7.3 libxml limits the maximum size of a single text node to 10MB. 
This limit can be removed with a new option, XML_PARSE_HUGE.

Bellow an example:

```
# Reads entire file into a string
$result = file_get_contents("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/68943?report=xml&format=text");
# Returns the xml string into an object
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);
```